# Granting Bluetooth permissions in Espresso for Android 12

Tags: android-espresso, android-12

I work on a legacy project. This project uses Bluetooth Low Energy to connect with devices. *Of course, I migrated the project to use the AndroidX libraries.* Some time ago I started to write tests in Espresso because it was the only way to test the Ble interface, since the Android Emulator doesn't support the Bluetooth emulation.

The App was targeting Android 11 and was compatible with previous versions until Android 6.

Of course I had to grant the permissions with a JUnit4 rule to avoid the permission popup:

```
@Rule public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Two weeks ago my company decided to target Android 12. So I replaced the rule with:

```
@Rule public GrantPermissionRule permissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
        android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
```

Unfortunately, this rule doesn't grant the permissions for Android 12, the app rises the permission popup and all my test (that previously worked fine) break.

I also tried this in the function labeled as `@Before`:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
                "pm grant " + ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + " android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN  android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT");
```

None of those solutions avoid the permission popup, so all our Bluetooth test brake.

Does anyone know how to grant the permissions for Espresso tests targeting Android 12?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while looking for a more elegant solution, the only way I can close the permission pop-up is to access to the acceptance button in one of these two ways:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
```

or

```
(withText(android.R.string.ok)).perform(click());
```

It wasn't the solution I wanted but it works.

Answer (score -1):

According to the developer documentation `GrantPermissionRule` is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html) and it is recommended to migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: Please, before giving a bad answer, search for more information. You posted a link to a deprecated class without checking if the AndroidX library has a class with the same name and the same goal: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule. Of course I migrated to AndroidX when I started to work in the legacy project.

Comment: I think the beginning of your question "I work on a legacy project" misled my answer. The fact that you have already migrated your project to AndroidX is important information to include in your question.

Comment: I think the fact that the app targeted Android 11 should be enough. Anyway I edit the question.